# What is the purpose of the section tag

Tags: html5, section

It seems that the HTML 5 `<section>` tag doesn't really add much beyond a `<div>` tag. Why should I use it, especially as it will not be compatible with anything below IE9?

Comment: Voting to close. This is [basic documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-section-element.html#the-section-element) and there are [thousands of articles](https://www.google.com/search?q=html5+section) explaining why `section` versus `article`, `div` etc.

Comment: @Su' - the question appears to be on-topic (SEO) and specific enough to be practically answerable - and, if we closed every question that can be answered with a Google search, this site wouldn't turn up in Google searches; if you post your link to the documentation as an answer I know you'll get at least one upvote.

Comment: @danlefree I disagree pretty much completely. But the votes will decide if it stays. If you want to discuss, start a thread in meta. No point hijacking the question.

Comment: @Su' [Done](http://meta.webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/769/html5-and-the-semantic-web-relevance-to-pro-webmasters) - let's dialogue.

Comment: did the OP did any research at all before this?

Comment: @slow diver, yes, I typed this question into google, and into SE, and the only answers I got were the definition of <section>, not what the actual purpose of it was, or why I should care.  Please feel free to educate me.

Comment: @jack I think I'm getting a better feel for what you're really after, but could you go read [this](http://html5doctor.com/the-section-element/) and [this](http://html5doctor.com/you-can-still-use-div/) and edit your question with some more detail re: what bothers you about the tag? The problem is `section` is weird as far as where or even *if* you should use it("if article, aside or nav is more appropriate"). Frankly you can just not use it if you don't want to and nobody will really care. It adds some semantics and organization to the document, but you won't lose much of anything without it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [HTML5 Living Standard](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/sections.html#the-section-element) describes a `section` as:

```
... a thematic grouping of content, typically with a heading ...
```

Consider an electronics product's page on an e-commerce site, for example, in which you list a product's "marketing-speak" description under one heading, a list of technical specifications under another heading, and a blurb about the manufacturer under yet another heading - each of those units of information could be considered a section of the document about the product.

You might be interested in using `section`s to help search engines and bots interpret these chunks of data as discrete logical entities with equivalent relation to the topic of the document, rather than as entities with relative relation to each other in order of appearance (as opposed to a story or expository essay).*

Because `section`s can effectively represent multiple themes with roughly-equivalent relevance to the document, it might make sense to use the `section` tag to organize panels on an interactive tabbed display (in which only one `section` displays at a time) - an unobtrusive Javascript could then scan documents for the `section` tag and, when it finds multiple `section`s, it could alter their CSS `position` and draw tabs to create the tabbed display.

*
it is presumptuous on my part to state that search engines are presently analyzing content at this level, but I wouldn't be surprised in the least if Google were, and when you author an HTML document and put it on a public server, it's safe to say that it's going to be analyzed by algorithms well into the foreseeable future.

Comment: On the IE9 support point, there are utilities like [html5shim](http://code.google.com/p/html5shim/) that will trick older versions of IE into behaving with most of the newer HTML5 tags. (HTML5shim is about the minimum, but do a little reading about "browser polyfills" and find one you like if you need more than just tag support; it's a whole topic on its own.)

Comment: but why should I be interested in helping a search bot "understand" versus having a web page that "works"

Comment: In this case the most-likely unnoticeable boost in rankings and traffic you could receive by making your site more accessible to bots is probably less valuable than the potential impact to users... but eventually your IE8 users will upgrade - at which point helping search bots understand your content will give you a competitive advantage. (Which is why it pays to take an interest now - you're in the best position to determine when to prioritize search bots' needs over the dwindling number of users on an obsolete browser)

Answer (score 0):

The most important difference is that `section` plays a role in the outline of the document, `div` not.

Document 1:

```
<body>
 <h1>foo</h1>
 <div>…</div>
 <h2>bar</h2>
</body>
```

Document 2:

```
<body>
 <h1>foo</h1>
 <section>…</section>
 <h2>bar</h2>
</body>
```

Document 1 has this outline:

1. foo (h1)

   1. bar (h2)

Document 2 has this outline:

1. foo (h1)

   1. (unnamed section heading)
   2. bar (h2)

Comment: As per @danlefree's answer, and as mentioned [here](http://html5doctor.com/the-section-element/), the heading should perhaps go _inside_ the `section`.

Comment: @w3d: _Moving_ one of those two headings inside the `section` would, of course, change the outline and thereby the semantics of the document (I deliberately chose this structure so that these two examples are the same except for `div` vs. `section`). So you'd want to (and should, but not must) _add_ a heading inside the `section`. The outline structure would not change but the "unnamed section heading" would have a name (that of the first heading in the `section`, no matter which level).